# How to check if a value is in a list in Django

Tags: django

I'm iterating through a list of all users and trying to check if the current user is following them.  The "in following" doesn't work.  Where am I going wrong here?

```
following = [<User: testaccount1>, <User: testaccount2>]

all_users_list = <QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'username': ‘testaccount1’},{‘id': 2, 'username': ‘testaccount2’},{‘id': 3, 'username': ‘testaccount2’}] 

{% for follow_user in all_users_list %}
    {% if follow_user.username in following %}
        FOLLOWING
    {% else %}
        Not Following
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: How exactly did you generate `all_users_list`?

Comment: I'm generating all_users_list in the view as:     all_users_list = User.objects.values()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop using `values()`. There are occasionally times when it is useful, but this is not one of them. Just pass the actual queryset: `User.objects.all()`.

Secondly, compare the actual objects, rather than comparing the username with the list:

```
{% if follow_user in following %}
```